# How can i compare between two funtions in python using =,>,<. I dont know how to revoke functions

Tags: python

```
def plus(x,y):

   return x+y

def multiply (u,z):

   return u*z

answer1 = int(input("what is x ?"))

answer2 = int(input("what is y? "))

answer3 = int(input("what is u ?"))

answer4 = int(input("what is z? "))

if plus > multiply:

   print("plus is bigger")

elif multiply > plus:

   print(" multiply is bigger")

else:

   print("they are equal")
```

Comment: What does “revoke function” mean?

Answer (score 5):

Call the functions:

```
if plus(x, y) > multiply(u, z):

   print("plus is bigger")

elif multiply(x, y) > plus(u, z):

   print(" multiply is bigger")

else:

   print("they are equal")
```

Or assign them first:

```
x = plus(x, y)
y = multiply(u, z)
if x > y:

   print("plus is bigger")

elif y > x:

   print(" multiply is bigger")

else:

   print("they are equal")
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't called the function.

This should work.

```
def plus(x, y):
    return x+y

def multiply(u, z):
    return u*z

answer1 = int(input("what is x ?"))
answer2 = int(input("what is y? "))
answer3 = int(input("what is u ?"))
answer4 = int(input("what is z? "))

Sum, Product = plus(answer1, answer2), multiply(answer3, answer4)

if Sum == Product:
    print("Equal")
elif Sum > Product:
    print("Sum is greater")
else:
    print("product is greater")
```

Comment: Don't override keyword names!